# Skip children validations with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two ActiveRecords `Author` and `Book`.

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books

  enum author_type: {
    musician: 0,
    scientist: 1
  }

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :books
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :score_url, presence: true
end
```

Now `Book` validates presence for both `name` and `score_url`, 
but I want skip validation for `score_url` when `author.author_type` is `scientist`.

I tried this way, but `author` can not be found during creation.

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :score_url, presence: true, if: "author.scientist?"
end
```

What is the best solution here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a `Proc` to the conditional validation

```
validates :score_url, presence: true, if: Proc.new { |book| book.author.scientist? }
```

if your validation gets any more complex, you should extract the logic to a new method.

```
validates :score_url, presence: true, if: :author_scientist?

private

def author_scientist?
  author.present? && author.scientist?
end
```